# User-entered data not being saved or appearing in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm having issues trying to append a core data entity called `products` - I used the same code that I used to add `companies`, which works fine. The only difference in the app is that there is just one "static" tableview of companies I guess you could say, whereas the tableview for products is dynamically set depending on which company cell is tapped. But I'm not sure how that would cause the problem.

I've been debugging/checking values all over the app since yesterday and it seems like no matter what I try to alter, `products.count` in `numberOfRowsInSection` remains `0`.

I call a function called `handleSave()` when the user hits a done button after entering new values in three text fields, just like with my other object `companies`:

```
func handleSave() {

    guard let newProductUrl = NSURL(string: urlTextField.text!) else {
        print("error getting text from product url field")
        return
    }
    guard let newProductName = self.nameTextField.text else {
        print("error getting text from product name field")
        return
    }
    guard let newProductImage = self.logoTextField.text else {
        print("error getting text from product logo field")
        return
    }


    self.productController?.save(name: newProductName, url: newProductUrl as URL, image: newProductImage)


    let cc = UINavigationController()
    let companyController = CompanyController()
    viewController = companyController
    cc.viewControllers = [companyController]
    present(cc, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

This then calls the `save` function to append `products`:

```
func save(name: String, url: URL, image: String) {

    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }

    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entity =
        NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Product",
                                   in: managedContext)!

    let product = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                  insertInto: managedContext)


    product.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
    product.setValue(url, forKey: "url")
    product.setValue(image, forKey: "image")

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        products.append(product)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And the data is fetched in `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }
    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let companyToDisplay = self.navigationItem.title!

    let fetchRequest =
        NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Product")

    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"company.name == %@",companyToDisplay)

    do {
        products = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        print(products)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

When this exact same process is used for adding `companies`, the new company then appears in the tableview. However now with products, that is not the case; the tableview remains empty. I'm not sure what the difference is and I'm not experienced enough with core data that I feel like I can figure out where the problem lies.

Huge thanks in advance to anyone that can figure this out!

Comment: @doxi45 hi have you tried printing values in save function?

Comment: @TusharSharma the `save` function in ProductController doesn't seem to get called. I.e. if I put a breakpoint on that function it doesn't interrupt the program, however if I put a breakpoint on the line in `handleSave()` that calls the `save` function (`self.productController?.save`), it interrupts. So I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: If that's true then `self.productController` is `nil`.

Comment: @d0xi45 I guess your navigation part is creating issue can you test it without navigation once o mean comment your code that present other controller and then put breakpoint on both function

Comment: @TusharSharma doing that has the same result except the view controller where the user adds the values is obviously not dismissed - but breakpoint on `save` does nothing while breakpoint on `self.productController?.save` in `handleSave()` crashes

Comment: @dan I'm confused as to what would cause that?

Comment: Are you setting it to a non-nil value anywhere?  I don't see that in your code.

Comment: @d0xi45 can you show us the complete code of both the controller.Can you edit your question?

Comment: @dan see my edit, I'm not sure if that's what you're talking about but let me know, @TusharSharma it's a lot of code here's the project in dropbox, the relevant controllers are `ProductController` and `AddProductController`: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17411581/NavCtrl.zip

Comment: I mentioned already in the other post that default initializers like `UINavigationController()` without any relation to the actual view hierarchy cannot work.

Comment: @vadian I thought you were talking about in relation to storyboard? This is all programmatic, I'm not using storyboard. What's the correct way in this scenario?

Comment: @vadian also this is the exact same code I used to save user-entered values for `companies` and that works, that's why I'm confused that it doesn't work now for `products`

Comment: Regardless of using storyboard or not you need the real (strong) references to the views and view controllers in the view hierarchy. `UINavigationController()` creates a new instance of a navigation controller which might be not the same as the actual visible controller.

Comment: @vadian I'm not sure how this could be causing the issue in my question since I used the same code for saving user-entered companies and it worked fine, so I'm trying to figure out why it won't work now with `products`.

Comment: @vadian do you know how I can change the code to make it work?

Comment: @d0xi45 I'm afraid no

Comment: @vadian ok, thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 0):

After invoking `handleSave()` & before performing `table.reloadData()`, you need to perform db fetch operations done in `viewWillAppear()`. 
Segregate your `fetchRequest` logic out of `viewWillAppear()` into a function called (say) `fetchUpdatedData()`.
Now, after `try managedContext.save()`, do a `fetchUpdatedData()`, update your `product` *data arrays* & then update the UI by `table.reloadData()`

Comment: I followed these suggestions (see my edit to see if I did so the way you intended) and the table is still not updated. I think the confusion is because each company on my first view controller has separate products, so the Product Controller table is dynamically set after the check of `navigationItem.title`. So perhaps the program doesn't know which company the products are being saved into? This is the project if you're curious to take a look (tap edit -> done -> select a company and try to add something: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17411581/NavCtrl.zip

Comment: Like I said in my question I'm especially confused because this same `handleSave()` -> `save` process, with the exact same code (minus fetching stock prices) is successful for adding companies. But products is a whole other ballgame. As a beginner to core data this is making my head spin.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `NSFetchedResultsController` to keep your view in sync with your model. `NSFetchedResultsController` monitors core-data and sends a delegate message when there are updates - then you can update your tableview. Otherwise you have to manually do a refresh whenever core-data changes.

Comment: I already have `NSFetchedResultsController` in my `ProductController` class definition (that's the controller that I get to the modal view `AddProductController` from, and am trying to return to. Do I also need to add it to `AddProductController`, along with any other methods, or change my `viewDidAppear`?